# MySQL UPDATE not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a bit of code which updates a table called `job`, but once the the page is executed it does not update the table. Here is the code:

```
$item = isset($_POST['item']);
$ref = isset($_POST['ref']);

$con = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con);

$sql="UPDATE job SET item = '$item' WHERE ref='$ref'";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
header("location:index.php");
```

I have echoed out the `$ref` variable and it is there but it won't work if I put it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: What is the value of `$sql` just before you execute the query? Also, beware of SQL Injection (you probably want to escape `$item` and `$ref` before putting them in a query).

Comment: What type of data is the $ref variable?

Comment: You realise that isset() returns a boolean true/false, not the actual value of the argument?

Comment: Please use bind variables to avoid severe SQL injection vulnerabilities!

Comment: @james The $ref is a string, i can echo out the value $ref correctly but it wont accept it in the clause.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger Yes i will escape and sanitise the data thanks (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ref = isset($_POST['ref']);
```

> I have echoed out the $ref variable and it is there

You aren't assigning the actual value of `$_POST['ref']`, you're only assigning whether or not it is set. Try:

```
$ref = isset($_POST['ref']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ref']) : NULL;
```

You can check your query by reading the SQL string you've created: `exit($sql)`

See also: [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

```
$item = isset($_POST['item']);
$ref = isset($_POST['ref']);
```

by this two statements, variables will have 0 or 1 as values ...better write this way..

```
$item = (isset($_POST['item']) == 1 ? $_POST['item'] : '');
$ref = (isset($_POST['ref']) == 1 ? $_POST['ref'] : '');

if($item !='' && $ref !=''){
   // your update query
}
```